# Debug JSFL for Adobe Animate CC?

Tags: debugging, flash, adobe, jsfl, animate-cc

Back when it was called flash, we could debug using the extendScript Toolkit editor. But that editor doesn't seam to support Adobe Animate, and the official docs say to edit JSFL in adobe animate. Animate has a debug panel, but no obvious options for debugging JSFL scripts.

If anyone knows a way to step through JSFL code I'd love to hear it. Until then I'm relying on fl.trace() :/

Comment: Did you have any luck, did you find a solution at all?

Comment: Nope :/ I gave up and just had to deal with fl.trace(). Good news is my company is phasing out flash and switching to AE so I don't need JSFL anymore.